# Laravel create custom exception with parameters & return as JSON

Tags: php, laravel

I want to throw a custom exception if the variable is null and return it as JSON.
I've tried like this:

**Controller**

```php
try {
    $check_api_key = $attendance_libraries->check_api_key($this->request);
    if ($check_api_key == null) {
        throw new NullException(false, 'API Key Not Found', null, 500);
    }
} catch (NullException $e) {
    return $e;
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // do something else           
}
```

**Custom Exception**

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

class NullException extends Exception
{
    public $is_success;
    public $message;
    public $code;
    public $data;

    public function __construct($is_success, $message, $code, $data = null, Exception $previous = NULL)
    {
        $this->is_success = $is_success;
        $this->message = $message;
        $this->code = $code;
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => $this->is_success,
            'message' => $this->message,
            'data' => $this->data,
        ], $this->code);
    }
}
```

But when I am trying to test it using postman, the return I got is not the same as I wrote in NullException. It becomes like this:
[image: Postman response]

Comment: Just replace `return $e;` with `throw $e;` in your controller. And really your method `check_api_key()` should be throwing the exception for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you are returning the exception as a response instead of throwing it. That's why it's displayed like this.

You could just have to throw the exception without the try/catch:

```php
$check_api_key = $attendance_libraries->check_api_key($this->request);

if ($check_api_key == null) {
    throw new NullException(false, 'API Key Not Found', null, 500);
}
```

The [laravel error handler](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors#rendering-exceptions) will catch the exception & render it.

**EDIT:** Or as @miken32 pointed out you could re throw the exception to handle other exceptions:

```php
try {
 //...
} catch (NullException $e) {
  throw $e;
} catch (// other exceptions) {
}
```

[image]

Comment: You're right they should be doing `throw $e` instead of `return $e` but the try/catch construct is still needed because they want to catch other types of exceptions and handle them.

Comment: Yes you are right ! I was just simplifying the explanation.

Comment: Don't simplify to the point of removing functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Returning the `render` method from **Exception** you are returning the **Exception**. And also you are passing the arguments in wrong order.

```
Route::get('exception', function () {
    try {
        $check_api_key = null;

        if ($check_api_key == null) {
            throw new NullException(
                is_success: false,
                message: "API Key Not Found",
                code: 500
            );
        }
    } catch (NullException $e) {
        return $e->render();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
    }
});
```